# Ranking array elements by occurrence rank

Tags: javascript

I have this a sentence, for example:

```
"car bicycle car bicycle car bicycle car bicycle car bicycle car bicycle plane plane
truck"
```

And I have an array of **words** frequency appearance in the sentence: `{ car: 6, bicycle: 6, plane: 2, truck: 1 }`

I must ended with ranking **1-5** like this (like 'stars' rating):

```
{ car: 5, bicycle: 5, plane: 2, truck: 1 }
```

When "5" is the most frequent, and "1" is the less one.

I can have have unlimited amount of unique "appearances", e.g:

`{ car: 6, bicycle: 6, plane: 2, truck: 1, name: 10, home: 3, bird: 12 }`

Comment: the *order* of the object matters?

Comment: You need to properly explain the logic behind this. Why did car and bicycle get “downgraded” from 6 to a 5, but plane and truck keep their exact existing values?

Comment: So converting from one scale to another basically? If yes, it seems that a simple cross-multiplication should do (plus some rounding/ceiling/flooring I suppose).

Comment: `{ car: 6, bicycle: 6, plane: 2, truck: 1 }` This is not an array, it is an object. And order does not matter in objects.

Comment: The "6" is number of appearances of the word "car". I need end up with scale 1-5

Comment: Your edits are helpful, don't give up. But this: "_When "5" is the most frequent, and "1" is the less one._" - how does one determine the rank between 5 & 1. What are those rules?

Comment: This for Ebay interview :). "5" if the word or words with the most appearance amount, So I can have more than 1 words with rank 1

Comment: so u just want it to max out at 5?

Comment: Yes, scale 1-5 is required

Comment: You would need to come up with some sort of algorithm to calculate a weight based on the number of appearances. That weight could then translate to your ranking

Comment: I would assume you are tracking key words over time to arrive at your ranking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds to me like you want to scale the counts to fit in the 1-5 range. If so, consider:

```js
function scale(ary, lower, upper) {
    let max = Math.max(...ary),
        min = Math.min(...ary);
    return ary.map(x => lower + Math.floor((upper - lower) * (x - min) / (max - min)));
}

//

let counter = { car: 6, bicycle: 6, plane: 2, truck: 1, name: 10, home: 3, bird: 12 }

let scaled = scale(Object.values(counter), 1, 5);

let result = Object.fromEntries(
    Object.keys(counter).map((k, n) => [k, scaled[n]])
)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: On this input: {
  car: 6,
  bicycle: 6,
  plane: 2,
  truck: 1
} the output is wrong

Comment: what output do you expect and why?

Comment: Expected  output is: { car: 5, bicycle: 5, plane: 2, truck: 1 }, because the word "plane" appear more than "truck", but they got same rank:  { car: 5, bicycle: 5, plane: 1, truck: 1 }

Answer (score 2):

If you want to max out at 5.. Is it this?

```js
function wordCount(text){
  let obj={}
  text.split(" ").forEach(a=>{
    if(!obj[a]){obj[a]=1} //for if new word
    else if(obj[a]<5){obj[a]++} //for if already counted word (< 5)
  })
  return obj
}

let string="car bicycle car bicycle car bicycle car bicycle car bicycle car bicycle plane plane truck"
console.log(wordCount(string))
```

Comment: How would you handle OP's last example? `{ car: 6, bicycle: 6, plane: 2, truck: 1, name: 10, home: 3, bird: 12 }` ? I don't think we have enough to get this chap a job with eBay yet. :-)

Comment: Then every item would have five "stars" if each of them occurs at least five times in the string.

Comment: hold up.. um, what do yall mean, where did `name` come from?

Comment: This `if(!obj[a]){obj[a]=1} else if(obj[a]<5){obj[a]++}` can also be written an as `if(!obj[a]) obj[a]=1; else if(obj[a]<5) obj[a]++;`

Comment: true but i like the brackets(for me mentally understanding)

Comment: @TheBombSquad I just mentioned it if somebody else likes that approach. (I also don't like it!)

Comment: On this input: { car: 6, bicycle: 6, plane: 2, truck: 1 } the output is wrong

Comment: @BallonUra what is the output SUPPOSED to be?

Comment: { car: 5, bicycle: 5, plane: 2, truck: 1 }

Comment: that's exactly what i have @BallonUra

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```js
let v = {
  car: 6,
  bicycle: 6,
  plane: 2,
  truck: 1
}
let maxVal = Math.max(...Object.values(v))
let maxRating = 5
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(v)) {
  console.log(`${key}: ${Math.ceil(value/maxVal * maxRating)}`);
}
```

Comment: Ah... my bad.. Did not see bomb-squads answer, which is far better. Sorry for the noise

Comment: On this input: let v = {
  car: 7,
  bicycle: 6,
  plane: 2,
  truck: 1,
} the output is wrong